# Use print dialog setting to print the desired options in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I want to show print dialog before printing a panel and then implement the selected options in the printed document. The options are something like Orientations, Number of copies, Page size (leter, A4, A3 , ...). How may I use the selected optionS? My code is like the following in my Winforms C# project now:

```
PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
    
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialog.Document = document;
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    
          PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
          doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);
          doc.Print();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Print Cancelled!");
    }
    
}
    
private void doc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
     Panel grd = splitContainer1.Panel2;
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(grd.Width, grd.Height, grd.CreateGraphics());
     grd.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 100, grd.Width, grd.Height));
     System.Drawing.RectangleF bounds = e.PageSettings.PrintableArea;
     float factor = ((float)bmp.Height / (float)bmp.Width);
     e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, bounds.Left + 20, bounds.Top, bounds.Width -40, factor * bounds.Width);
}
```

Actually the above code shows the print dialog, but nothing is implemented in the printed page.

Answer (score 1):

To get any changes made in the dialog window, you can look at `PrintDialog`. You would then have to set those changes in `PrintDocument` before the `doc.Print` line, like so:

```
doc.PrinterSettings = dialog.PrinterSettings;
```